# Unity 2018.4.15f1 : BuildMethodException in Unity when trying build for Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I've seen this issue floating up on various StackOverflow questions, but none of the solutions seem to have helped me out, and there seem to be multiple solutions to the problem (in case you see this as a duplicate question).

I'm trying to build an XR Application for Android using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ml2UakwRxjk). But when I try to build and run the project on my Android device (Android 9.0) I get this error:

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: Error building Player because scripts have compile errors in the editor
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00242] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:194 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:97 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:179)
```

I tried finding the files mentioned in the error, but couldn't locate them.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?